# DotNetNuke Not showing the action menu on multiple copies of a module

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am working on a DNN site and I am working on injecting an existing module into the page. I'm having a problem where once the module is injected, any other instances of the module won't show the action menu when in edit mode. I need to figure out how to make the action menu show up for all instances of a module.

I am using this code to do the injection:

```
Pane pane = new Pane((HtmlContainerControl)this._htmlContainer);
ModuleInfo miModuleToInject = GetModuleInfo(iModuleID);

miModuleToInject.ContainerPath = "";
miModuleToInject.ContainerSrc = "";
miModuleToInject.DisplayTitle = false;
miModuleToInject.StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
miModuleToInject.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date;

pane.InjectModule(miModuleToInject);
```

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors on the page?

Comment: Nothing related to it. I got the answer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a similar issue last week, where only the first module on a page had a working action menu.

In my case it was an extra  tag in the ascx of the offending module.

Drove me nuts trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. Long shot I know but I often forget to check the simple stuff first!

Comment: Your welcome, you may be the first person I have heeled on here!